# Fetching more than 10000 Records from MongoDB takes 5 mins index present on collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi I have a mongo collection EntityRecords which has index on State and EntityReferenceId column . The structure of Collection is like this .

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584a7119a0297fc8becafe40"),
    "EntityReferenceId" : BinData(3,"+DVL5D2m6UGgs8p/RHEvfw=="),
    "ReferenceId" : 1135517158,
    "State" : 3,
    "ResolveStrategyForEntireRow" : 0,
    "Comments" : null,
    "LastUpdatedBy" : null,
    "ChangeLog" : null,
    "Fields" : [
            {
                    "Name" : "TravelWorkID",
                    "Value" : 1068501,
                    "DisplayValue" : "1068501"
            }
    ],
    "Changes" : [
            {
                    "FieldName" : "InspectorType",
                    "DisplaySourceValue" : "O",
                    "DisplayLocalValue" : "",
                    "DisplayLastImportedValue" : "",
                    "SourceValue" : "O",
                    "LocalValue" : null,
                    "LastImportedValue" : null,
                    "Value" : null,
                    "ResolveStrategy" : 3
            }
    ]
```

}

I want to get all records with EntityReferenceId and state as filters . The query returns 138100 records but it is taking more than 6 mins to get all data (note for reporting purpose i need to process all records returned in my C# class) . I have used this query .

```
 db.getCollection('EntityRecords').
  find({'EntityReferenceId':UUID("F8354BE43DA6E941A0B3CA7F44712F7F" ) ,
  $or: [ { State: 3 }, { State: 4 },
        { State: 7 }, { State: 5 }, { State: 6 }   ]       }).
       explain('executionStats') ;
```

The problem is in my C# code it taken 6 mins to get all records can you please help me how can I make it faster / parallel is possible .

The execution stats is below .

```
   db.getCollection('EntityRecords').
   find({'EntityReferenceId':UUID("F8354BE43DA6E941A0B3CA7F44712F7F" ) ,
    $or: [ { State: 3 }, { State: 4 },
           { State: 7 }, 
           { State: 5 }, { State: 6 } ]  }).explain('executionStats')
 {
    "queryPlanner" : {
            "plannerVersion" : 1,
            "namespace" : "SIR.EntityRecords",
            "indexFilterSet" : false,
            "parsedQuery" : {
                    "$and" : [
                            {
                                    "$or" : [
                                            {
                                                    "State" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 3
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "State" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 4
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "State" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 7
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "State" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 5
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "State" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 6
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    ]
                            },
                            {
                                    "EntityReferenceId" : {
                                            "$eq" : BinData(3,"+DVL5D2m6UGgs8p/RHEvfw==")
                                    }
                            }
                    ]
            },
            "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                            "filter" : {
                                    "$or" : [
                                            {
                                                    "State" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 3
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "State" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 4
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "State" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 7
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "State" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 5
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "State" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 6
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    ]
                            },
                            "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                    "keyPattern" : {
                                            "EntityReferenceId" : 1
                                    },
                                    "indexName" : "EntityReferenceId_1",
                                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                                    "direction" : "forward",
                                    "indexBounds" : {
                                            "EntityReferenceId" : [
                                                    "[BinData(3, F8354BE43DA6E941A0B3CA7F44712F7F), BinData(3, F8354BE43DA6E941A0B3CA7F44712F7F)]"
                                            ]
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            },
            "rejectedPlans" : [
                    {
                            "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
                            "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                                    "filter" : {
                                            "EntityReferenceId" : {
                                                    "$eq" : BinData(3,"+DVL5D2m6UGgs8p/RHEvfw==")
                                            }
                                    },
                                    "inputStage" : {
                                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                            "keyPattern" : {
                                                    "State" : 1
                                            },
                                            "indexName" : "State_1",
                                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                                            "direction" : "forward",
                                            "indexBounds" : {
                                                    "State" : [
                                                            "[3.0, 3.0]",
                                                            "[4.0, 4.0]",
                                                            "[5.0, 5.0]",
                                                            "[6.0, 6.0]",
                                                            "[7.0, 7.0]"
                                                    ]
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
            "executionSuccess" : true,
            "nReturned" : 138100,
            "executionTimeMillis" : 192,
            "totalKeysExamined" : 138100,
            "totalDocsExamined" : 138100,
            "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
                    "nReturned" : 138100,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 150,
                    "works" : 138101,
                    "advanced" : 138100,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needFetch" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 1080,
                    "restoreState" : 1080,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                            "filter" : {
                                    "$or" : [
                                            {
                                                    "State" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 3
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "State" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 4
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "State" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 7
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "State" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 5
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "State" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 6
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    ]
                            },
                            "nReturned" : 138100,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 150,
                            "works" : 138101,
                            "advanced" : 138100,
                            "needTime" : 0,
                            "needFetch" : 0,
                            "saveState" : 1080,
                            "restoreState" : 1080,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "invalidates" : 0,
                            "docsExamined" : 138100,
                            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                            "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                    "nReturned" : 138100,
                                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 60,
                                    "works" : 138101,
                                    "advanced" : 138100,
                                    "needTime" : 0,
                                    "needFetch" : 0,
                                    "saveState" : 1080,
                                    "restoreState" : 1080,
                                    "isEOF" : 1,
                                    "invalidates" : 0,
                                    "keyPattern" : {
                                            "EntityReferenceId" : 1
                                    },
                                    "indexName" : "EntityReferenceId_1",
                                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                                    "direction" : "forward",
                                    "indexBounds" : {
                                            "EntityReferenceId" : [
                                                    "[BinData(3, F8354BE43DA6E941A0B3CA7F44712F7F), BinData(3, F8354BE43DA6E941A0B3CA7F44712F7F)]"
                                            ]
                                    },
                                    "keysExamined" : 138100,
                                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                    "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                                    "matchTested" : 0
                            }
                    }
            }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
            "host" : "DTA641-045",
            "port" : 27017,
            "version" : "3.0.4",
            "gitVersion" : "0481c958daeb2969800511e7475dc66986fa9ed5"
    },
    "ok" : 1
```

}

Comment: It may not help, but change that `$or` to an `$in` - it's easier to read and add more values. Also, have you looked at aggregation for this? Why are you also getting 10k records? Have you looked at `skip()` and `limit()`?

Comment: I tried with $in as well  but no difference in query plan . The issues is we need to fetch all records into our system to create a log  and we have more than 10000 records as it contain data for past 5 years . and based of each year data we create comparison result (i.e which is done in C# ) . SO O was wondering why mongo return records after 5 minutes  .

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ  
I tried with $in as well but no difference in query plan . The issues is we need to fetch all records into our system to create a log and we have more than 10000 records as it contain data for past 5 years . and based of each year data we create comparison result (i.e which is done in C# ) . SO O was wondering why mongo return records after 5 minutes